# Dynamic menus and submenus with Caliburn Micro, how can I bind the commands?

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro, commandbinding

I am using Caliburn Micro in a WPF project where I want plugin components to be able to populate a toolbar. Each plugin gets a top level menu item and can populate it with submenus if they choose.

[image: Example]

```
<ToolBar>
    <Menu x:Name="ToolBarMenuItems">
        <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Text}" />
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=Children}" />
            </Style>
        </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
    </Menu>
</ToolBar>
```

ToolBarMenuItems is a BindableCollection of an interface:

```
public BindableCollection<IMenuItemViewModel> ToolBarMenuItems { get; set; }

public interface IMenuItemViewModel
{
    string Text { get; set; }

    ObservableCollection<IMenuItemViewModel> Children { get; set; }

    bool CanRunCommand();

    void RunCommand();
}
```

This works fine as far as creating the menu goes, the problem is connecting the menu items to the RunCommand/CanRunCommand. [Dynamic menus with Caliburn micro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988705/dynamic-menus-with-caliburn-micro) explained how to do it on a MenuItem:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem x:Name="ToolBarMenuItems" DisplayMemberPath="Text" Header="MyMenu" cal:Message.Attach="RunToolbarCommand($originalsourcecontext)"/>
</Menu>
```

Where RunToolBarCommand is a method in the view model `public void RunToolbarCommand(IMenuItemViewModel menuItem)` and $originalsourcecontext refers to setting the following in the bootstrapper

```
MessageBinder.SpecialValues.Add("$originalsourcecontext", context =>
{
    var args = context.EventArgs as RoutedEventArgs;
    var fe = args?.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
    return fe?.DataContext;
});
```

But as I said, I need to do this for the entire menu and not just on a MenuItem, but I don't know how to use Caliburn Micro to bind the methods.

Comment: i dont understant your problem, could you elaborate?  you have a tips functional for menuitem, but where is your problem about binding method? show a sample of what you want..sorry for my english

Comment: Basically the working example I have is for a MenuItem where each object in the list would be a submenuitem. If I had standard menus like File, Edit, Plugins etc. this would be perfect, I would put it on the Plugins MenuItem and each plugin would get a submenu to play around with.

I don't want it on the MenuItem though, I want it on the Menu and each object in the collection should be a top level MenuItem on that Menu. This is because I want a toolbar where each plugin gets a top level MenuItem where it can add submenus if it needs.

Comment: I added an image to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a setter to your `Style` that sets the `cal:Message.Attach` attached property and passes the `$executionContext`:

```
<Menu x:Name="ToolBarMenuItems">
    <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Text}" />
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=Children}" />
            <Setter Property="cal:Message.Attach" Value="RunCommand($executionContext)" />
        </Style>
    </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
</Menu>
```

You need the context in your interface and implementation to be able to stop the event from bubbeling:

```
public void RunCommand(ActionExecutionContext context)
{
    if (context?.EventArgs is RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        routedEventArgs.Handled = true;

    MessageBox.Show("Run!");
}
```

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29234509/menuitem-event-called-multiple-times) question for more information about this.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you so much! I failed to realize that cal:Message.Attatch could be used as the property of the style, even though now it seems obvious when I see it (as so often is the case).